# Stub Resolv::DNS UDPSocket requests in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, udp, webmock

I have the problem, where ruby 2.4.3p205 can't handle domains with german umlauts in them. For example when you try this you get an error

```
[1] pry(main)> Resolv::DNS.new.getresource("exämple.com", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::MX)    
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/resolv.rb:823:in `[]='
```

The fix is to convert the domain first into punycode, and then pass it to `Resolv::DNS`. I can also verify that `#getresource` is called with the punycode domain.

But I digged a little deeper and debugged into the resolv.rb from ruby. There I found out it uses `UDPSocket` to do the request. Coming from awesome tools like webmock I immediately thought "I just stub out the UDP call and can verify that the request is made with the punycode domain".

But as it turns out, webmock can't stub such requests (otherwise it would be named "udpmock" or something like this), so I was wondering if there is either a library for this, or how to do it. IMHO it could be messy to spy on rubys `UDPSocket` and return fake objects, but I can't imagine another way to do it.

Comment: I believe, you are going to stub wrong thing. There is `Resolv::DNS::Name` where you can do monkey-patching. Converting to punycode is client-side duty.

Comment: I did something like that(locally I m-patched it): https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13385